# What is the serialization format of PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Looking at the code for [ResultSet](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java#AbstractJdbc2ResultSet), all the get*** (getFloat, getBigDecimal) assume that the underlying object is a String. However the code for [JDBCStatement](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Statement.java#AbstractJdbc2Statement) seems to just call getObject on ResultSet and cast to the proper type (instead of calling get Float, etc.)

Does the PostgreSQL driver send data over as String or using some sort of serialization protocol? What part of the code takes care of de-serialization?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking about here. The JDBC driver by the sounds, but do you want to know about the wire protocol format - i.e. what's sent on the network? About Java object serialize/deserialize for members of the result set?

Comment: (1)The wire protocol, (2) where in the code is deserialization done